# If my function fails for whatever reason, should I return an error value, e.g. false or -1, or throw an exception?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

For example if I have a function that expects a specific type of input:

```
function processArray(array) {
    if(!Array.isArray(array)) {
        // throw exception or return something?
    } else {
        // code
    }
}
```

What should I do if the type precondition is violated? What about other general errors that I might encounter? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: Javascript has exceptions.  You should use them.

Comment: it depends what you need later.

Comment: Does your processing code return something in the normal path?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/159096/66652

Comment: @Bergi I was wondering if that was it. So you're saying, if it doesn't return anything then throw an exception and if it does then return an obviously erroneous value?

Comment: @Bluefire It depends. Do you want to make all the callers check the result before using it?'

Comment: Rather the reverse. If you normally return something useful, you should use exceptions, if you don't have anything to return you might as well return a status code instead